# Google Maps Place request from browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

Trying to get a request from a React app to Google Maps API working but getting CORS issues. Google says it supports CORS but not sure how to make the right request to be able to retrieve place data.

```
const src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=${GOOGLE_API_KEY}&placed=${id}&fields=formatted_phone_number`

const headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
}

fetch(src, { mode: 'cors', headers: headers }).then(response => console.log(response))
```

The src itself is fine but getting this issue:

> Failed to load
>   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=(keyRemoved)&placed=(placeRemoved)&fields=formatted_phone_number:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use the Places service in the Javascript API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/places-service#PlacesService